# Strange Bug in my code with D3.JS and Bar Charts

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, d3.js

Hi guys im learning D3 and im trying to make dynamic charts which with changing the chart group will show the same group charts let me show you with two images:

[image: First Image]

[image: After Filter]

i followed the documents tutorials which are working ! but the behave iof my code is
weird when i apply the filter by selecting the group
it shows bars in random locations or on top of each others
also after filter apply it never shows the very first bar of array
here is the code

```
var cereals;
    if (manufacturer === 'All')
        cereals = data.filter(d => d.manufacturer !== manufacturer);
    else cereals = data.filter(d => d.manufacturer === manufacturer);

    // **** Draw and Update your chart here ****
    var bars = chartG.selectAll('.bar')
        .data(cereals,function(d,i){
            return d.sugar;
        });

    var barsEnter = bars.enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'bar');
    
    barsEnter.merge(bars)
        .attr('transform', function(d,i){
            return 'translate('+[i * barBand + 4,0]+')';
        });
    
    
    /*barsEnter.append('rect')
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("width", barWidth)
            .attr("height", function(d) { return chartHeight - sugarScale(d.sugar); });
    */
    barsEnter.append('rect')
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return sugarScale(d.sugar); })
    .attr("width", barWidth)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return chartHeight - sugarScale(d.sugar); });
     
    barsEnter.append('text')
        .attr('dy', '0.9em')
        .attr('dx', '0.6em')
        .attr('class','axis-label')
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + chartHeight + ")")
        .text(function(d){
            console.log(d)
            return d.cerealName;
        }); 
    bars.exit().remove();
```

Here is full code if you want to check!

main.js

```
// Global function called when select element is changed
function onCategoryChanged() {
    var select = d3.select('#categorySelect').node();
    var category = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    // Update chart with the selected category of cereal
    updateChart(category);
}

// recall that when data is loaded into memory, numbers are loaded as strings
// this function helps convert numbers into string during data preprocessing
function dataPreprocessor(row) {
    return {
        cerealName: row['Cereal Name'],
        manufacturer: row['Manufacturer'],
        sugar: +row['Sugars']
    };
}

var svg = d3.select('svg');

// Get layout parameters
var svgWidth = +svg.attr('width');
var svgHeight = +svg.attr('height');

var padding = { t: 60, r: 20, b: 80, l: 60 };

// Compute chart dimensions
var chartWidth = svgWidth - padding.l - padding.r;
var chartHeight = svgHeight - padding.t - padding.b;

// Variable for the spacing of bar charts
var barBand;
var barWidth;

// scales
var sugarScale; // y axis
var xBandScale; // x axis

// Create a group element for appending chart elements
var chartG = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${padding.l}, ${padding.t})`);

var data;

d3.csv('cereals.csv', dataPreprocessor).then(function(dataset) {
    // Create global variables here and intialize the chart
    data = dataset;

    // Compute the spacing for bar bands based on number of cereals
    barBand = chartWidth / data.length;
    barWidth = 0.7 * barBand;

    // **** Your JavaScript code goes here ****\
    dataset
    
    // Add axes to chart
    addAxes();

    // Main Part
    sugarScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.sugar; })]);0


    chartG.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(sugarScale)).append("text").text("value");
    
    
    // Update the chart for All cereals to initialize
    updateChart('All');
});

function addAxes() {
    // **** Draw the axes here ****
    sugarScale = d3.scaleLinear().range ([chartHeight,0]),
    xBandScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, chartWidth])
}

function updateChart(manufacturer) {
    //  Create a filtered array of cereals based on the manufacturer
    var cereals;
    if (manufacturer === 'All')
        cereals = data.filter(d => d.manufacturer !== manufacturer);
    else cereals = data.filter(d => d.manufacturer === manufacturer);

    // **** Draw and Update your chart here ****
    var bars = chartG.selectAll('.bar')
        .data(cereals,function(d,i){
            return d.sugar;
        });

    var barsEnter = bars.enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'bar');
    
    barsEnter.merge(bars)
        .attr('transform', function(d,i){
            return 'translate('+[i * barBand + 4,0]+')';
        });
    
    
    /*barsEnter.append('rect')
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("width", barWidth)
            .attr("height", function(d) { return chartHeight - sugarScale(d.sugar); });
    */
    barsEnter.append('rect')
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return sugarScale(d.sugar); })
    .attr("width", barWidth)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return chartHeight - sugarScale(d.sugar); });
     
    barsEnter.append('text')
        .attr('dy', '0.9em')
        .attr('dx', '0.6em')
        .attr('class','axis-label')
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + chartHeight + ")")
        .text(function(d){
            console.log(d)
            return d.cerealName;
        }); 
    bars.exit().remove();
}

// Remember code outside of the data callback function will run before the data loads
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lab 4 - ABCs of D3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <svg width="600" height="330" style="border: 1px solid #777;">
        </svg>
        <div>
            <label for="categorySelect">Manufacturer: </label>
            <select class="custom-select" id="categorySelect" onchange="onCategoryChanged()">
              <option selected value="All">All</option>
              <option value="General Mills">General Mills</option>
              <option value="Quaker Oats">Quaker Oats</option>
              <option value="Ralston Purina">Ralston Purina</option>
              <option value="Kelloggs">Kelloggs</option>
              <option value="Nabisco">Nabisco</option>
              <option value="Post">Post</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="./main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Styles

```
.axis-label {
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: semibold;
}

body {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    margin: 0;
}

.bar {
    fill: #4571C9;
}
#main {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

cereals.csv

```
Cereal Name,Manufacturer,Sugars
Kix,General Mills,3
Life,Quaker Oats,6
Trix,General Mills,12
Smacks,Kelloggs,15
Basic 4,General Mills,8
Crispix,Kelloggs,3
All-Bran,Kelloggs,5
Cheerios,General Mills,1
Clusters,General Mills,7
Wheaties,General Mills,3
100% Bran,Nabisco,6
Bran Chex,Ralston Purina,6
Corn Chex,Ralston Purina,3
Corn Pops,Kelloggs,12
Rice Chex,Ralston Purina,2
Special K,Kelloggs,3
Grape-Nuts,Post,3
Honey-comb,Post,11
Wheat Chex,Ralston Purina,3
Apple Jacks,Kelloggs,14
```

This is example of strange bug :

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 possible things:

1. You're adding class bar to your 'g' elements AND the 'rect' elements within the 'g' element - I can see that causing issues when you selectAll on that class
2. You're appending new rects and texts after you merged the new and existing bars. This will add more texts and rects to the existing bars. You want to append the text and rect elements before the merge.

Not necessary but might be nice:
2a) You might want to after the merge operation, 'select' the rect and do the bar Y/width/height calculation there so existing bars are updated if the values changed since the last operation. This looks like static data at the moment though.